# GraphQL return null to the 3rd root child but generated in backend function

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I was working on the query which populate data which have `images objects`, on returning to the client side I am updating these object into `string`. 
My `query` is working fine till this stage but when I try to update these string and make them objects and it worked if it is 1st or 2nd child but when it comes to 3rd child it stopped working and returning `null` on the client side but it showed in the `backend` and it generated `successfully`.

Can be more understand easily by this method.

```
Query{
   fetchProducts{
       id
       images: {
          generated successfully
       }
       category: {
          id
          images: {
             generated succesfully
          }
          child_category:{
             id
             images: {
                **not generated**
             }
          } 
       }
   }
}
```

So when it comes to third child it doesn't generate images and it return `null` for it.

I have searched and try many methods for it but doesn't help.

What should be the reason for it?

I am also posting my queries and which have the same scenario and as you so it is working on 1 function but it is not working in another.

Working Query.

```
{
  fetchProducts{
    id
    images_sizes{
      small
      large
      standard
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

As you see in the image you didn't find any `null` as it is returning the right format.

But when I run this query which have the same schema and have the same format but it doesn't return any thing.

```
{
 fetchSingleHomepage{
    sections{
      image_sizes{
        small

      }
      products{
        images_sizes{
          small

        }
        defaultImage_sizes{
          small
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your resolver code, otherwise it's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: Resolver code is return what this function return, there is nothing in resolver, just calling this function and the name of the resolver function is save as the this function.

Comment: All you have shown is the queries and responses. Whatever problem exists in your code, so you should include all the relevant code. SO guidelines state that "questions seeking debugging help... must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." In other words, you need to include [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).